# looking at the selections of foods

Tags: grammar, word-choice

She stood at the counter in a Starbucks **looking at the selections of foods.**

Is the last part of the sentence natural at all? If not, what could I write instead? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence as you quote it didn't really sound that unusual to me until I thought about it a little bit. 
But I do see what you mean.

It's a minor point, but because "selections" is pluralized, "the *selections* of foods" implies more than one selection. A "selection" is just an idea that exists in the mind of the speaker/writer (just a mental grouping of the food items that exist). So I guess we really can't say for sure that there aren't multiple "selections" of foods present at Starbucks.

But in my opinion Starbucks doesn't have that large an abundance of choices for food (*Coffee* might be another matter). I think it would be more appropriate to just speak of "the selection" in the singular here. The Starbucks company has selected a certain set of foods to offer for sale; this is the "selection [singular] of foods" that "she" was looking at.

If you phrase the sentence this way:

> She stood at the counter in a Starbucks looking at the selection of
>   foods.

it sounds completely natural and idiomatic to me.

On the other hand, if the situation were a little different, it might be quite appropriate to use "selection*s* of foods":

> She went down the street from cafe to cafe, comparing the different
>   *selections of foods*.

That sentence sounds fine.

Comment: It sounds more natural to me to use the singular *food*. However, there's nothing actually wrong with the plural *foods*.